# In a VS Code Extension, open the markdown preview of the README.md of the extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to be able to show a markdown preview of the README.md file from the extension with a command palette option. I understand how to open a file from the open folder of the active VS Code window, but how do I access a file from the repo of the extension?

I have this, but it gives an error

```js
context.subscriptions.push(
      vscode.commands.registerCommand('new-extension.showReadMe', async () => {
        const docs = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument('../README.md')
        await vscode.window.showTextDocument(docs)
      })
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `asAbsolutePath` function provided by the [`ExtensionContext`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions) type to generate an absolute path to a file that is part of the extension.
An instance of `ExtensionContext` is passed into an extension's `activate` function.

In the following example, the Markdown preview of an extension's `README.md` file is displayed as the extension is activated:

```js
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    const readmePath = context.asAbsolutePath("README.md");
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("markdown.showPreview", vscode.Uri.file(readmePath));
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly